# Angular 7: Adicionar vários parâmetros na URL com HttpParams

Tags: angular, http-headers

Lendo a documentação do angular eu consegui desenvolver o seguinte método de pesquisa com filtros, mas o problema é que preciso de uma pesquisa com vários filtros e não apenas 1 como mostra o código abaixo desenvolvido por mim. Tentei de várias formas mas não tive sucesso em adicionar vários parâmetros na URL...

```
consultar(filtro: PacienteFiltro): Promise<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('admin' + ':' + 'admin')
      }),
      params: filtro.nome ? new HttpParams().set('nome', filtro.nome) : {}
    };

    return this.http.get(this.url, httpOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

**Criar o objeto httpOptions normalmente sem os params:**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('admin' + ':' + 'admin')
  })
}
```

**Depois efetuar a seguinte parametrização (Este passo vai vincular os parâmetros ao header):**

```
const requestOptions = Object.assign({}, httpOptions);

requestOptions['params'] = Object.assign({}, filtro);
```

**O código ficará assim:**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('admin' + ':' + 'admin')
  })
};

const requestOptions = Object.assign({}, httpOptions);

requestOptions['params'] = Object.assign({}, filtro);

return this.http.get(this.url, requestOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response);
```